# Retrieving Maximum Of One Column For Each Unique Value From Another

Tags: mysql, sql

What I've attempted and which returns incorrect data:

```
SELECT type, pid, MAX(distance) FROM table GROUP BY type
```

This retrieves every unique `type` and the correct corresponding maximum `distance` for each `type` from my database (there are a total of 26 different unique `type` values and this will never change), but the `pid` values are incorrect. How can I retrieve the correct and corresponding `pid` values?

Example table data:

```
pid  | type | distance  | ...
675  | dcj  | 273060192 | ...
743  | mcj  | 273046176 | ...
284  | dcj  | 271592224 | ...
4091 | lj   | 255217488 | ...
743  | lj   | 255170160 | ...
4091 | lj   | 230840928 | ...
```

What should be returned:

```
pid  | type | distance
675  | dcj  | 273060192
743  | mcj  | 273046176
4091 | lj   | 255217488
```

Some notable information about the data:
There are multiple entries per `pid` value and there may be multiple entries per `pid` value that have the same `type` value.

Do I need to utilize PHP to run two different queries where the first one grabs the 26 different `type` values via `GROUP BY type` and the second query is executed 26 different times (once per unique `type` value) and finds the maximum for each `type` via something like `WHERE type="' . $type . '" ORDER BY distance DESC LIMIT 1`? Or can this be done in one SQL query?

Comment: can you define what "correct and corresponding" means, please?

Comment: It sounds like you want a 'Groupwise Maximum' ... check out this article for a number of approaches: http://kristiannielsen.livejournal.com/6745.html

Comment: @Tom Mac: correct and corresponding = true value of pid actually stored in the same row of the maximum distance value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query gives the desired result.

```
SELECT t.type, t.pid, t.distance
FROM table t
INNER JOIN (SELECT type, MAX(distance) as distance FROM table GROUP BY type) as m
ON t.type = m.type and t.distance = m.distance
ORDER BY t.type
```

It will return all pid that have the same maximum distance for the ( not very probable ) case that two or more pid have the same maximum distance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `GROUP BY` query, them join it to the original table to get the right `pid`, like this:

```
SELECT x.type, t.pid, x.max_dist
FROM (
    SELECT type, MAX(distance) as max_dist FROM table GROUP BY type
) as x
JOIN table t ON x.max_dist=t.distance AND x.type=t.type
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f813/4).

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible using a common table expression:

```
;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   pid,
                        type,
                        distance,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY distance DESC ) AS RowNum
               FROM     table_name
             )
    SELECT  pid,
            type,
            distance
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   RowNum = 1
```